# Losing sort order in python dictionary after converting from list of tuples

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary

So I have a dictionary which needs to be sorted by values. I sort them with below Python3 function which returns sorted data as a list of tuples.

```
def sorter(data):
    return  sorted(data.items(), key=lambda kv: kv[1], reverse=True)
```

It sorts the data perfectly, but when I convert this list back to dictionary by

```
dict(sorter(data))
```

It loses the order and returns a dictionary in a completely random order.
What am I missing here?

Comment: Which version of Python 3, specifically?

Comment: Dictionaries are not considered ordered in Python <3.7. You should use `collections.OrderedDict` instead.

Comment: version is Python 3.3.1
I know that dictionaries are not ordered, but when I convert an ordered list of tuples to dictionary, shouldn't it take the first element in the list and put them as first key-value pair in dictionary?

Comment: @MherHarutyunyan Before python 3.7, dicts simply didn't have a concept of "first".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Dictionaries in Python are implemented as hash tables, which are inherently unordered – or rather, they are ordered arbitrarily and may change their order upon any modification.

This was [changed in Python 3.7](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dictionary-view-objects), where dictionaries keep their insertion order. But relying on this will make your code less portable.

Use [`OrderedDict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) if you want to keep the ordering on all Python versions:

```
from collections import OrderedDict
OrderedDict(sorter(data))
```

Answer (score 1):

As the comments say, dictionaries aren't ordered (until Python 3.7).

If you need an ordered dict, use the aptly named `collections.OrderedDict`.

```
import collections

def sorter(data):
    return sorted(data.items(), key=lambda kv: kv[1], reverse=True)

d = collections.OrderedDict(sorter(data))
```